# Can clerics' Combat Feats be used with summoned Spiritual Weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats, cleric, summoning

While looking at Pathfinder's **Blibdoolboolp** and the stats given to her clerics (for giggles), I noticed that her Holy Weapon was a Pincer Staff (which has grapple). So I'm wondering, are a clerics Combat Feats usable by a summoned spiritual weapon?

For instance, if you had the feat *Sleeper Hold* and your spiritual weapon was grappling someone with its *grapple* trait, would the weapon be able to use your *Sleeper Hold* feat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Pathfinder SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/spiritualWeapon.htm) says specifically, "Your feats or combat actions do not affect the weapon". Indeed, I'm not sure a weapon's special abilities such as grapple apply to spiritual weapons.  The spell description also says it attacks as a spell, not as a weapon.

Comment: That's not the pathfinder SRD though, that's the 3.5 SRD

Comment: @willuwontu, ah, my mistake.  However, that text also appears in https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spiritual-weapon/, as does the statement that it attacks as a spell, not a weapon.

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't noticed until this question was linked elsewhere.